# Is There a Way to Inject A Dependency to a Helper Class Using IoC Container?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, servicestack, servicestack-ioc

I have a helper class that I'm instantiating in one of my services. I was wondering if there is a way to inject the Repository using the IoC container and have it as a property instead of passing the auto-wired repository from the service.

This is because this helper class is implementing an interface and other classes that does implement this might not necessarily need to take that in that specific method.

I'm trying to solve this without changing a lot of code.

```
public class SomeService : Service
{
    public IRepository Repo { get; set; }
    public object Get(Request req)
    {
        var helper = new SomeServiceHelper();
        var somethingFromHelper = helper.GetSomething();

        var SomethingFromRepo = Repo.GetSomethingElse();

        .
        .
        .
    }

    public object Post(Request req)
    {
        Repo.SaveSomething(something);
    }
}

public class SomeServiceHelper : IHelper
{
    public IRepository Repo { get; set; }
    public object GetSomething()
    {
        Repo.GetSomethingFromDB();

        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be okay to make the SomeServiceHelper class static?

Comment: You can't make it static, because static classes cannot implement interfaces

Answer (score 1):

> This is because this helper class is implementing an interface and other classes 
>   that does implement this might not necessarily need to take that in that specific method.

You don't need to register your helper class against an interface, you can just register the concrete type, e.g:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<SomeServiceHelper>();
```

Or:

```
container.Register(c => new SomeServiceHelper {
    Repo = c.Resolve<IRepository>(),
});
```

Then you could have either or both injected in your Service:

```
public class SomeService : Service
{
    public SomeServiceHelper Helper { get; set; }
    public IRepository Repo { get; set; }
}
```